# What JS codes should I add to do the following?

Tags: javascript, html, css

kinda new to this JS stuff so I want someone to please help me to do the following

- I want to add appropriate JavaScript event handlers so that when the user clicks on any of the A’s in the “fontControl”, the font size for all of the article adjusts to 0.8em, 1.0em and 1.3em.
- In addition the color of the selected A should be set to blue and the color for the other two A’s grey.
- when the mouse cursor hovers over any A, the background color for that A should turn white.

I would appreciate it if anyone would help me out. 
Thank you, cheers.

```js
<script>
function init()
{

    document.getElementById('small').onclick = function()
    {
        document.getElementById('content').style.fontSize = "0.8em";

    }
    document.getElementById('medium').onclick = function()
    {
        document.getElementById('content').style.fontSize = "1.0em"
        
    }
    document.getElementById('large').onclick = function()
    {
        document.getElementById('content').style.fontSize = "1.3em"
        
    }
    
}

window.onload=init;
</script>
```

```css
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Articles</title>

<style>
* {
    margin: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    font: 1em Verdana, sans-serif;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
}
h2, h4 {
    text-align: center;
}

#header {
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    padding: 0.5em 0;
    height: 100px;
}
#footer {
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    padding: 1em 0;
}
#header, #footer {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #CCC;
}
#leftnav, #rightnav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    width: 20%;
    padding-top: 3em;
}

#rightnav{ 
    left: 80%;
}
#wrapper {
    background-color: dodgerblue;    overflow: hidden;
}
#content div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
#content div:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
    
#content div:hover {
    border-color: dodgerblue;
    background-color: white;
}
    
#content {
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 0 20%;
 border-left: 2px solid black;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    background-color: white;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------------*/
span {
    color: #777;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#small {
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
#medium {
    font-size: 1em;
    color: dodgerblue;
}
#large {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

#fontControl {
    float: right;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

    
    
</style>
```

```html
<body>
<div id="header">
    The Header
</div>

<div id="wrapper"> <!-- Can be used to apply bg colour -->

<div id="leftnav">
    <h4> Left</h4>
</div>
<div id="rightnav">
    <h4> Right</h4>
</div>
    
<div id="fontControl" >
    <span id="small">A</span>
    <span id="medium">A</span>
    <span id="large">A</span>
</div>    
    
<div id="content">
    <div>
        <h2> Article 1 </h2>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            Suspendisse ultricies condimentum velit vel scelerisque.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2> Article 2 </h2>
        <p>
            Mauris sagittis aliquam odio vitae pulvinar.
            Suspendisse id dolor nibh, sed consectetur sem.
            Phasellus lacinia laoreet sem, ac ultrices libero lobortis quis.
            Morbi accumsan tempus neque, sed varius lectus molestie imperdiet.
            Vivamus porttitor facilisis nunc, sed feugiat quam adipiscing ac.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2> Article 3 </h2>
        <p>
            Proin ultrices lectus vel orci lacinia a iaculis nibh hendrerit.
            Mauris sagittis aliquam odio vitae pulvinar.
            Suspendisse id dolor nibh, sed consectetur sem.
            Phasellus lacinia laoreet sem, ac ultrices libero lobortis quis.
            Morbi accumsan tempus neque, sed varius lectus molestie imperdiet.
            Vivamus porttitor facilisis nunc, sed feugiat quam adipiscing ac.
        </p>
    </div>
</div> <!-- end of content -->
    
</div> <!-- end of wrapper -->
    
<div id="footer">
<h3>
    The End
</h3>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a code/SQL/regex writing service, where you post a list of your requirements and language of choice and a code monkey churns out code for you. We're more than happy to help, but we expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. Once you've done so, you can explain the problem you're having, include the **relevant** portions of your work, and ask a specific question, and we'll try to help. Good luck.

Comment: Yes i get you, but I still do need help to do it, I would be fine by just explaining what I need to do, I would do it myself :D

Comment: *appropriate JavaScript event handlers so that when the user clicks on any of the A* ..hint: `aElement.addEventListener('click', handler)` ... *color of the selected A should be set to blue ..* hint: `aElement.style.color='blue'` ... *when the mouse cursor hovers over* ... hint: `aCssSelector:hover { background-color: white}`

Comment: Thank you Jaromanda, that's what I need

Comment: When asking questions on SO, it is best to keep things as [mcve] as possible. We don't need the whole layout of the page, just the parts relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do, is use [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) to attach a single event handler to `#fontControl` to handle all font size changes. This makes it easy to add new sizes and means if you need to change anything you have just one handler to edit instead of several.

Also, instead of directly altering the color of the indicators, I would add and remove a 'selected' class to them.

```js
let elContent = document.getElementById('content');
let elFontControl = document.getElementById('fontControl');

elFontControl.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  // target is the element that was clicked on, either one of the spans
  // inside of #fontControl, or #fontControl itself
  let target = event.target;

  // we want to ignore clicks on #fontControl, so only proceed if
  // a span was clicked on
  if (target.tagName === 'SPAN') {
    // remove the selected class from the previously selected item
    elFontControl.querySelector('.selected').classList.remove('selected');

    // add the selected class to the item that was clicked
    target.classList.add('selected');
    // set the fontSize to the computed fontSize of the clicked item
    elContent.style.fontSize = window.getComputedStyle(target).fontSize;
  }
});
```

```css
#small {
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
#medium {
    font-size: 1em;
}
#large {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
#extra-large {
    font-size: 2em;
}
#extra-small {
    font-size: .5em;
}
#fontControl {
    color: grey;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

#fontControl .selected {
    color: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="fontControl" >
    <span id="extra-small">A</span>
    <span id="small">A</span>
    <span id="medium" class="selected">A</span>
    <span id="large">A</span>
    <span id="extra-large">A</span>
</div>    
    
<div id="content">
    <div>
        <h2> Article 1 </h2>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            Suspendisse ultricies condimentum velit vel scelerisque.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2> Article 2 </h2>
        <p>
            Mauris sagittis aliquam odio vitae pulvinar.
            Suspendisse id dolor nibh, sed consectetur sem.
            Phasellus lacinia laoreet sem, ac ultrices libero lobortis quis.
            Morbi accumsan tempus neque, sed varius lectus molestie imperdiet.
            Vivamus porttitor facilisis nunc, sed feugiat quam adipiscing ac.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2> Article 3 </h2>
        <p>
            Proin ultrices lectus vel orci lacinia a iaculis nibh hendrerit.
            Mauris sagittis aliquam odio vitae pulvinar.
            Suspendisse id dolor nibh, sed consectetur sem.
            Phasellus lacinia laoreet sem, ac ultrices libero lobortis quis.
            Morbi accumsan tempus neque, sed varius lectus molestie imperdiet.
            Vivamus porttitor facilisis nunc, sed feugiat quam adipiscing ac.
        </p>
    </div>
</div> <!-- end of content -->
```

This code assumes that the size indicators that you click on have the actual `fontSize` that you will change to. [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) gets the effective size of the font. You can't just use `.style.fontSize` since the size was set via class, not directly on the element with the `style` attribute.

If the size of the indicator was not exactly the same, you could instead store the size info in a [`data-` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) and then access it via [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

```js
let elContent = document.getElementById('content');
let elFontControl = document.getElementById('fontControl');

elFontControl.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  // target is the element that was clicked on, either one of the spans
  // inside of #fontControl, or #fontControl itself
  let target = event.target;

  // we want to ignore clicks on #fontControl, so only proceed if
  // a span was clicked on
  if (target.tagName === 'SPAN') {
    // remove the selected class from the previously selected item
    elFontControl.querySelector('.selected').classList.remove('selected');

    // add the selected class to the item that was clicked
    target.classList.add('selected');
    // set the fontSize to the computed fontSize of the cliked item
    elContent.style.fontSize = target.dataset.fontSize;
  }
});
```

```css
#small {
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
#medium {
    font-size: 1em;
}
#large {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
#extra-large {
    font-size: 2em;
}
#extra-small {
    font-size: .7em;
}
#fontControl {
    color: grey;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

#fontControl .selected {
    color: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="fontControl" >
    <span id="extra-small" data-font-size=".25em">A</span>
    <span id="small" data-font-size=".8em">A</span>
    <span id="medium" class="selected" data-font-size="1em">A</span>
    <span id="large" data-font-size="1.5em">A</span>
    <span id="extra-large" data-font-size="5em">A</span>
</div>    
    
<div id="content">
    <div>
        <h2> Article 1 </h2>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            Suspendisse ultricies condimentum velit vel scelerisque.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2> Article 2 </h2>
        <p>
            Mauris sagittis aliquam odio vitae pulvinar.
            Suspendisse id dolor nibh, sed consectetur sem.
            Phasellus lacinia laoreet sem, ac ultrices libero lobortis quis.
            Morbi accumsan tempus neque, sed varius lectus molestie imperdiet.
            Vivamus porttitor facilisis nunc, sed feugiat quam adipiscing ac.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2> Article 3 </h2>
        <p>
            Proin ultrices lectus vel orci lacinia a iaculis nibh hendrerit.
            Mauris sagittis aliquam odio vitae pulvinar.
            Suspendisse id dolor nibh, sed consectetur sem.
            Phasellus lacinia laoreet sem, ac ultrices libero lobortis quis.
            Morbi accumsan tempus neque, sed varius lectus molestie imperdiet.
            Vivamus porttitor facilisis nunc, sed feugiat quam adipiscing ac.
        </p>
    </div>
</div> <!-- end of content -->
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best solution but hopefully it will help you.

- In addition the color of the selected A should be set to blue and the
  color for the other two A’s grey.

call this function every time the A is clicked.

> changeAColor('large');

```
function changeAColor(id){
    var spans = document.getElementById("fontControl").childNodes;   
   for(var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++){
        if(i % 2 != 0)
        spans[i].style.color = "grey";   
   }

   document.getElementById(id).style.color = "dodgerblue"
}
```

- when the mouse cursor hovers over any A, the background color for
  that A should turn white.

Add this to your CSS

```
span:hover{
  background-color: white;  
}
```

**Working Example**
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lb5pmjnf/14/)